# Donut Caching ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a possibility to do Donut Caching with MVC2? Even with a lot of research I was not able to find a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donut caching does not work with ASP.NET MVC 2, see http://forums.asp.net/t/1521502.aspx :

> Supporting donut caching would require view engines to be able to send an array consisting of literal text + callbacks to the writer.  This is a major plumbing change and is not something that will be included in v2 of the product.

Answer (score 1):

Not Supported != Not Possible

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/07/01/Extending-ASPNET-MVC-OutputCache-ActionFilterAttribute-Adding-substitution.aspx

http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/output-donut-caching-attribute-asp-net-mvc-partial-requests

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx

Comment: Those links are all for MVC1.0. Substitution was removed from MVC2.0

Answer (score 1):

Cross-post from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685906/is-donut-caching-available-in-asp-net-mvc-3/6994582#6994582):

Donut Caching (yes, the real thing) is available as part of my 'speed-lib' for MVC: [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth). Works in both ASP.NET MVC 2 and MVC 3.

Docs are at [the wiki](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/wiki/Server-side-caching), and examples are in the [Mvc3.Demo](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/blob/master/Mvc3.Demo/Views/Home/OutputCaching.cshtml) folder.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be useful. It is possible using Html.Action and passing HttpContextBase instance to the child controller.
Check it
http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/donut-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-2-with-html-action/

but I don't know if it works properly so far...